# Quand est-ce que « qu » se prononce /kw/?

Tags: prononciation

On a les mots *quatre*, *quand*, *quai*, *quorum*, et beaucoup d’autres dans lesquels « qu » se prononce /k/.

Mais en revanche on a *équation*, qui se prononce /e.kwa.sjɔ̃/, *quatuor*, et *quoi*. Et puis on a *loquace*, qui (il me semble) se prononce **ou** /lɔ.kas/ **ou** /lɔ.kwas/. Et *quota* aussi permet les deux prononciations (selon Wiktionary).

Y-a-t’il une règle, un schéma en ce qui concerne l’absence ou la présence du phonème /w/?

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu /lɔ.kwas/.

Comment: Je ne pense pas qu'il puisse y avoir de réponse plus précise que cette page de la *Banque de dépannage linguistique* : [Prononciation de la suite de lettres *qu*](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/23645/la-prononciation/prononciation-de-certaines-lettres/prononciation-de-la-suite-de-lettres-qu). En France je n'ai non plus jamais entendu [lɔkwas] et je pense que [kɔta] est plus répandu mais les dictionnaires indiquent les deux. Wiktionary n'est pas toujours fiable, mais le TLF l'est : [quota](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quota), [loquace](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/loquace).

Comment: pour "quoi", le /w/  vient de "oi", pas de "qu"

Comment: @None, dans la scolarité hexagonale, c'est ‘*lokace*’.

Comment: Je trouve /lɔ.kwas/ vieilli aussi mais pas impossible chez moi. Sauf que contrairement à ce que l'OQLF dit, je prononce définitivement _requiem_ ʁe.kwi.ɛm et non pas comme le début de cuillère. En fait à bien y penser, je prononce aussi aquifère, équidistant et équilatéral avec kwi et non kɥ. Montréal sans doute.